# Can two Skinshifters affect each other?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have two [Skinshifter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skinshifter)s in play, can I use the ability of one to affect the other?  For instance, if one of my Skinshifters has [Ice Cage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ice%20Cage) on it, can I use the other Skinshifter's ability to morph the "caged" one, thereby breaking the Ice Cage?

Answer (score 12):

**No, you can't.**

Breaking an [Ice Cage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=245283) on a [Skinshifter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=skinshifter) with another Skinshifter's ability won't work for 2 reasons:

**First** and most straightforward, the Skinshifter's ability does not require a target, and Ice Cage requires the enchanted creature to be *targeted* by a spell or ability for it to break.

**Second**, you can use Skinshifter's ability only to change itself, not another Skinshifter.

If a card says "Something happens to *CARD NAME*", then this always references the card this text is printed on, unless explicitly stated otherwise. If a card references another card by name, the syntax is always something like "A card/creature named *XY*", for example like [Llanowar Sentinel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=129536), or [Angel's Herald](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=175141).

The rules for that is [this](http://www.wizards.com/magic/comprules/MagicCompRules_20110930.txt):

> 201.4. Text that refers to the object it's on by name means just that particular object and not any other objects with that name, regardless of any name changes caused by game effects.

Comment: I would have switched your order. While the first rule you listed may be the most straightforward, the second is the most important. ;)

Comment: thanks guys.  Just getting back into it, and the rules have gotten a bit more complicated.

Comment: AFAIK, the "Text that refers to the object it's on by name" rule has been around since the beginning of the game.